# How to display rows of data from a DataView using a string variable instead of srting builder class

Tags: c#, asp.net

Working with DataViews: Is it possible to simply display the rows and column using a string variable instead of a string builder?

The method below gets the rows. However, without a `String Builder` appending the values, I am unable to get each row on it's own ***straight line***.

```
    public string DisplayDataRow(DataView dataView)
    {
        string rows = null;
        string lineBreak = "<br />";

        foreach(DataRowView rowView in dataView)
        {
            for(int index = 0; index < dataView.Table.Rows.Count; index++)
                rows += rowView.Row[index] + lineBreak;
        }

        return rows;
    }
```

The rows are returned like this:

```
1003248739
5
Lykam
Abel
2/11/2015 12:00:00 AM

1003146780
5
Longbine
Abel
2/9/2015 12:00:00 AM

1001136448
1
Cerutti
Abel
2/10/2015 12:00:00 AM

1000854556
2
Roos
Abe
2/10/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

How do I get an output so that the rows are like this?

```
1003248739 5 Lykam Abel 2/11/2015 12:00:00 AM
1003146780 5 Longbine Abel 2/9/2015 12:00:00 AM
1001136448 1 Cerutti Abel 2/10/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding line break after every column what you need to do is add it after every row like this

```
    public string DisplayDataRow(DataView dataView)
{
    string rows = null;
    string lineBreak = "<br />";

    foreach(DataRowView rowView in dataView)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < dataView.Table.Rows.Count; index++)
            rows += rowView.Row[index] + " ";
        rows+=lineBreak;
    }

    return rows;
}
```